# Delphi: Generic type inference of reference argument

Tags: delphi, generics, type-inference, delphi-xe

What's the best way to get around the shortcoming of generic type inferencing of reference arguments, **so that I don't have to specify the type in every call**?

**Update**: I don't mind other (including non-generic) solutions as long as it works with multiple (any?) types.

This seems to still not have been resolved, although known for quite some time.

**Please vote for a resolution to this on Embarcaderos Quality Central: [Issue #78103](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78103).**

From a [comment](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=244&cpage=1#comment-107) by [Barry Kelly](http://blog.barrkel.com) to [Generic Methods and Type Inferencing](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=244):

> PS: Your example, in Tiburon, almost works. Method type inference works well for arguments passed by value. It doesn’t work for arguments passed by reference, unfortunately (the compiler is being too strict).

Now, almost three years later, I'm trying the same thing in Delphi XE, and it complains that:

> [DCC Error] INIv1_Parser.pas(81): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

When calling:

```
function FindDataItemValue<T>(ItemType: TDataItemType; out Value: T): Boolean;
```

With:

```
var MaxG: Real;
...
if Data.FindDataItemValue(PAR_MaxG, MaxG) and (MaxG = 2.5) then ...
```

*Commonly suggested work-around*: However, if I **add the  generalization on the call, it works** fine; although annoying that it is even needed.

**Update**:

Thus far, The best I've come up with is to use either Variants or the TValue record from the Rtti module. Using variants I implement interfaces when I need to use objects, and store a reference to that (interface) in the variant.

Comment: I don't feel I've got a single suggestion about how to really get around the issue. The only suggestions so far is to add the type to the call, which is what I would like to get rid of. I'll edit my original question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference does not currently work for var and out parameters. I agree that it is highly annoying.

Comment: The answer then, becomes: there is no work-around. Or, the work-around is to avoid generics altogether.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround. You have to specify the type.

```
var
  MaxG: Real;
...
  if Data.FindDataItemValue<Real>(PAR_MaxG, MaxG) and (MaxG = 2.5) then ...
```

If you want Embarcadero to resolve this, then vote for [this QC entry that is about your issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=78103).

The QC entries with the highest votes get more attention.

Comment: Thanks for the link to QC issue [#78103](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78103). I've voted for it.
Thanks to Thorsten Engler for reporting it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do exactly what's demonstrated in the article you cite: Include the type parameters in the method call:

```
if Data.FindDataItemValue<Real>(PAR_MaxG, MaxG) ...
```

Comment: Well, that makes it work. However, I would like to get rid of the `<PotentiallyLongAndComplicatedTypeName>`-syntax; even if I have to sacrifice the use of generics altogheter, which are rather buggy when it starts to get complex any way (or I'm not using generics correctly).